# C# Switch statement querying MYSQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a program that if user selects something from dropdown then a label will show depending on what is selected.

EG:

selects Dog from dropdown the label will show "Dog is £20"

selects Cat from dropdown the label will show "Cat is £15"

I am not doing it correct and have been at it for hours any help would be much appreciated.

**Code so far**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER= 000.000.00.000;username=myusername;password=******; Initial Catalog = mydatabase");
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pets", cs);
   cs.Open();
   MySqlDataReader ddl = cd.ExecuteReader();
   DdPetPist.DataSource = ddl;
   DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
   DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
   DdPetPist.DataBind();
   cs.Close();
   cs.Dispose();
}
```

**Select Index Change**

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CAST(Specie AS varchar) + '#' + CAST(Specie_Price AS varchar) AS Specie FROM pets", cs);
   cs.Open();
   PetPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(cd.ExecuteReader());
   cs.Close();
}
```

Please any help will be great I have been stuck on this problem for hours and would like to move on to my next task at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selection = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    string petPrice = string.Empty;

    MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM pets WHERE Specie ='{0}'",selection), cs);
    cs.Open();
    petPrice = Convert.ToString(cd.ExecuteScalar());
    cs.Close();

    petPrice.Text = String.Format("{0}  is £{1}", selection, petPrice);
}
```

**EDIT :** Also, in page_Load, you need to wrap the code in if(!IsPostBack), like below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pets", cs);
       cs.Open();
       MySqlDataReader ddl = cd.ExecuteReader();
       DdPetPist.DataSource = ddl;
       DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
       DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
       DdPetPist.DataBind();
       cs.Close();
       cs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: problem with  `petPrice.Text = String.Format("{0}  is £{1}", selection, petPrice);`   but i will see if i can fix it

Comment: Also, don't forget to wrap the code in Page_load with `if(!IsPostBack){}`. Else `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` will be null.

Comment: Top Marks @afzalulh I can only hope to be as good as you one day, works well thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try set the AutoPostBack property in true from the dropdown. Or put a breackpoint in this line

```
PetPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(cd.ExecuteReader());
```

and tell me what value have"PetPrice.Text".

Comment: PetPrice.Text will be the label that the query will be output, I think there is a problem with my query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change ExecuteReader to ExecuteScalar

```
PetPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(cd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Also your Page_Load is updating everything on every load, including postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
   MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pets", cs);
   cs.Open();
   MySqlDataReader ddl = cd.ExecuteReader();
   DdPetPist.DataSource = ddl;
   DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
   DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
   DdPetPist.DataBind();
   cs.Close();
   cs.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm thanks for you reply, I think there is a problem with my query as well as when I select a different option from the drop down the label is not changing.

Comment: Looks like you also are re-loading the dropdown on every page load. Wrap the contents of the Page_Load in an `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { }` block.

Comment: Thank you, programs still not doing what i would like it to do, but il keep working on it.